# data structure of input for tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, structure, dimension

I am new to `tensorflow`. Working on a project of image prediction.

•assume I have 100 images, each one has been transferred into a matrix.(or simply using `'ImageDataGenerator'`).

•Then I need to cut the matrix into 3 small matrices. Use the first 2 of them as input and the last 1 as output.

•The idea is to training 90 of the images in this way and then use the neural networking to predict the last part-matrix of the rest 10 images.

Question :
1.do I need to pair the first 2 part-matrices together? or will the model only accept single input?

2.is it necessary to differ the first part-matrix to the second part-matrix?

3.what if I want to add the coordinates into the input, so I can have different cutting positions for each images?

Comment: I am a bit confused, do you want to split the dataset in training, testing and validation datasets? Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, it is similar as I have a photo which has a missing part (of course the missing part is relatively small than the other parts). I want to predict the missing part with the parts I have.